# Tree symbol style set?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, style, 2d

I am looking for a set of 2d tree symbols style for a landscape plan.  I got an old one trees.avi that I can't import to 10.0.
Can anybody link me to one?

Answer (score 9):

There is a nice [ESRI blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/11/12/symbolizing-trees-in-arcgis-assigning-each-species-a-different-symbol/) on building your own vector tree symbols.  I personally use these for this same purposes and they look great.  There are also some instructions on randomizing tree sizes [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/03/11/symbolizing-trees-in-arcgis-10-randomly-varying-the-tree-symbol-size-and-rotation-angle/).

Answer (score 2):

To provide a more recent option to look into, I would suggest [Preset layers](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/symbols-and-styles/preset-layers.htm) and to check out the list of [Supported tree genus types](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/symbols-and-styles/supported-tree-genus-types.htm)

[image]; [image]

> Preset layers are one way to add data to a map or scene. When you add a preset layer, you choose the type of layer you want, and then you navigate to a corresponding dataset. Preset layers are well suited for sharing across the platform. Some preset layers also include a streamlined set of symbology properties.

You could also check in the symbol selector [Searching for symbols](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/styles-and-symbols/finding-symbols.htm)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use font symbol, standard arcgis installation come with lot of symbol font, including some with tree.

The "ESRI US Forestry 2" for exemple but you cpould also look for other free font on the web.

Be careful, if you share your mxd or export to pdf or illustrator format you will need to check that the people you share with have the font on their machine or the symbol will not correctly be displayed

[image]